# Codeigniter 3: update Sql table column via GET superglobal

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pdo, crud

I am working on a **Register and Login** application with CodeIgniter 3 and Bootstrap.

In my "users" table I have an "active" column that can take **either 0 or 1** as value.

[image]

I want to be able to change the value of the "active" column corresponding to a user from 0 to 1 (activate the user) by clicking a link in my *users view*:

[image]

The "Activate" button code in the *users view*:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>users/activate/<?php echo $user->id ?>" title="Enable" class="btn btn-success btn-xs activate-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Enable</a>
```

Still in the *users view* every table row has the id of the *user*:

```
<tr id="<?php echo $user->id ?>">
```

In my **Usermodel** model I have:

```
public function activateUser($user_id) {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('users', ['id' => $user_id]);
    return $query->row();
}
```

In my **User** controller I have:

```
public function activate($user_id) {
    $this->load->model('Usermodel');
    $user = $this->Usermodel->activateUser($user_id);
    if ($user->active == 0) {
        echo 'activate user';
    }   else {
        echo 'user already active';
    }
}
```

The url `users/activate/1` returns "user already active" , while `users/activate/2` returns "activate user", as expected. Being new to Codeigniter, I have tried numerous versions of the code above that resulted in errors:

```
public function activateUser($user_id) {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('users', ['id' => $user_id])->update('users', $data);
    return $query->row();
}
```

is one of those versions resulting in **errors**.

Can you please tell me what shall I change in the code to make work as desired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, activateUser should update the database row for that user and then return all updated user information. You are trying to mash two queries together that should be separate. Just take it in two steps:

```
public function activateUser($user_id) {
    $user = null;

    $updateQuery = $this->db->where('id', $user_id)->update('users', ['active' => 1]);
    if ($updateQuery !== false) {
        $userQuery = $this->db->get_where('users', ['id' => $user_id]);
        $user = $userQuery->row();
    }

    return $user;
}
```

I put in a little bit of error checking; if for instance the user id was not valid this will return `null`.

Based on that error checking, your controller code might look something like:

```
public function activate($user_id) {
    $this->load->model('Usermodel');
    $user = $this->Usermodel->activateUser($user_id);

    // $user->active will always be 1 here, unless there was an error

    if (is_null($user) {
        echo 'error activating user - check user id';
    } else {
        // I was assuming you would want to do something with the user object,
        // but if not, you can simply return a success message.
        echo 'user is now active';
    }
}
```

Comment: How would your code look in the **context** of my *Usermodel* model?

Comment: I modified the answer to show that I was working with the query in `activateUser()`.

Comment: What about the `activate($user_id)` function, how should it look like?

Comment: That depends on what you want to return to the client, I guess. I'll add some code above to guess what you might intend.